# Not all request payload making it to the serializer Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

A DRF newbie here, so please be patient with me :)

I'm trying to update an object with a Serializer and for some reason I can't get all the request payload to the Serializer, one of the fields is missing. I must say that this field is not part of the model that is linked with the Serializer, but looking at the docs, this seems not to be an issue...I can add whatever fields I want.

That said, this is my model:

```
class Product(AbstractProduct):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name=_(u'Name'))
    school = models.ForeignKey('school.School')
    level = models.ForeignKey(
        'school.Level',
        verbose_name=_(u'Level')
    )
    age = IntegerRangeField()
    gender = models.CharField(choices=GENDER_CHOICES, max_length=1, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name=_(u'Gender'))
    num_sessions = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(verbose_name=_(u'Number of sessions'),
    default=1,
    help_text=_(u"Number of sessions that the product has."),
    )

    addons = models.ManyToManyField('self',
        verbose_name=_(u'Administrators'),
        through='AddonInService',
        symmetrical=False,
        related_name='addon_can_be_used_in'
    )

    class Meta(AbstractProduct.Meta):
        verbose_name_plural = _(u'Products')
```

This is my ProductViewSet, nothing special as you can see...

```
class ProductAPIViewSet(NestedViewSetMixin, viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer

    @property
    def pagination_class(self):
        if 'offset' in self.request.query_params:
            return CustomLimitOffsetPagination
        else:
            return CustomPageNumberPagination
```

Finally, here is my Serializer

```
class AddonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    price = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = (
            'id',
            'title',
            'name',
            'slug',
            'description',
            'price',
        )

    def get_price(self, obj):
        Selector = get_class('partner.strategy', 'Selector')
        selector = Selector()
        strategy = selector.strategy()
        stock_info = strategy.fetch_for_product(obj)
        return stock_info.price.incl_tax

class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    age = IntegerRangeField()
    addons = AddonSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    price = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    color = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = [
            'id',
            'structure',
            'upc',
            'title',
            'slug',
            'description',
            'rating',
            'date_created',
            'date_updated',
            'is_discountable',
            'name',
            'age',
            'gender',
            'num_sessions',
            'parent',
            'product_class',
            'school',
            'level',
            'school_category',
            'addons',
            'color',
            'price',
        ]

    def get_price(self, obj):
        Selector = get_class('partner.strategy', 'Selector')
        selector = Selector()
        strategy = selector.strategy()
        stock_info = strategy.fetch_for_product(obj)
        return stock_info.price.incl_tax

    def validate(self, data):
        school = data.get('school')
        level = data.get('level')
        view = self.context['view']
        school_id = view.kwargs['parent_lookup_school']
        school = School.objects.get(id=school_id)

        if level and level.school != school:
            raise serializers.ValidationError(
                {'level': _(u'The level must be a level created by the school. ')
             })

        school_category = data.get('school_category')
        if school_category is not None and school_category.school != school:
            raise serializers.ValidationError({'school_category':
             _(u'All the categories must be the categories created by the school.')}
            )

        return data

    def get_color(self, obj):
        try:
            color = obj.school_category.color
        except:
            color = ''
        return color

    def create(self, validated_data):
        product = Product.objects.create(**validated_data)
        return product

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        for attr, value in validated_data.items():
            if attr in 'price':
                print('found price!!!')
            else:
                setattr(instance, attr, value)
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

Ok, now imagine in my front-end I create a request to modify an existing product, request payload is like this:

```
{
    "school": 1,
    "school_category": 1,
    "name": "Surfing board",
    "slug": "object-object",
    "level": 3,
    "num_sessions": 1,
    "age": {
        "upper": 65,
        "lower": 18,
        "bounds": "[)"
    },
    "addons": [{
        "id": 6,
        "title": "Photography",
        "name": "Photography",
        "slug": "",
        "description": "Nice pics",
        "price": 206.87
    }],
    "gender": "F",
    "description": "a nice board",
    "price": 2111
}
```

Thus, I'm expecting to get "2111" in the serializer update method, but nope, I'm getting nothing. Thus, I checked the validate method to see what was getting there:

```
(Pdb) l
85      
86          def validate(self, data):
87              import pdb
88              pdb.set_trace()
89              school = data.get('school')
90  ->          level = data.get('level')
91              view = self.context['view']
92              school_id = view.kwargs['parent_lookup_school']
93              school = School.objects.get(id=school_id)
94      
95              if level and level.school != school:
(Pdb) print data
OrderedDict([(u'slug', u'object-object'), (u'description', u'a nice board'), (u'name', u'Surfing board'), (u'age', NumericRange(18, 65, u'[)')), (u'gender', 'F'), (u'num_sessions', 1), (u'school', <School: school_1>), (u'level', <Level: advanced>), (u'school_category', <Category: Surf <school_1>>)])
```

As you can see, there is no price neither addons being passed to the Serializer...

If I create an instance of the ProductSerializer, I can see the fields...

```
In [1]: from test.applications.catalogue.serializers import ProductSerializer

In [2]: ps = ProductSerializer()

In [3]: print repr(ps)
ProductSerializer():
    id = IntegerField(label='ID', read_only=True)
    structure = ChoiceField(choices=(('standalone', <django.utils.functional.__proxy__ object>), ('parent', <django.utils.functional.__proxy__ object>), ('child', <django.utils.functional.__proxy__ object>)), label='Product structure', required=False)
    upc = CharField(allow_blank=True, allow_null=True, help_text='Universal Product Code (UPC) is an identifier for a product which is not specific to a particular  supplier. Eg an ISBN for a book.', label='UPC', max_length=64, required=False, validators=[<UniqueValidator(queryset=Product.objects.all())>])
    title = CharField(allow_blank=True, max_length=255, required=False)
    slug = SlugField(max_length=255)
    description = CharField(allow_blank=True, required=False, style={'base_template': 'textarea.html'})
    rating = FloatField(read_only=True)
    date_created = DateTimeField(read_only=True)
    date_updated = DateTimeField(read_only=True)
    is_discountable = BooleanField(help_text='This flag indicates if this product can be used in an offer or not', label='Is discountable?', required=False)
    name = CharField(max_length=50)
    age = IntegerRangeField()
    gender = ChoiceField(allow_blank=True, allow_null=True, choices=(('M', <django.utils.functional.__proxy__ object>), ('F', <django.utils.functional.__proxy__ object>)), required=False)
    num_sessions = IntegerField(help_text='Number of sessions that the product has.', label='Number of sessions', max_value=32767, min_value=0, required=False)
    school = PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=School.objects.all())
    level = PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Level.objects.all())
    school_category = PrimaryKeyRelatedField(allow_null=True, label='Category', queryset=Category.objects.all(), required=False)
    addons = AddonSerializer(many=True, read_only=True):
        id = IntegerField(label='ID', read_only=True)
        title = CharField(allow_blank=True, max_length=255, required=False)
        name = CharField(max_length=50)
        slug = SlugField(max_length=255)
        description = CharField(allow_blank=True, required=False, style={'base_template': 'textarea.html'})
        price = SerializerMethodField()
    color = SerializerMethodField()
    price = SerializerMethodField()
```

Any idea why I'm not getting the price - addons in the Serializer? Thanks!

**EDIT:** Based on the documentation and on the above answer, I fixed this by changing the field to be an IntegerField

```
price = serializers.IntegerField()
```

And then moved added a method in the model itself

```
@property
def get_price(self):
    Selector = get_class('partner.strategy', 'Selector')
    selector = Selector()
    strategy = selector.strategy()
    stock_info = strategy.fetch_for_product(self)
    return stock_info.price.incl_tax
```

This effectively works, and looks way cleaner...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of the fact that you are using a `SerializerMethodField` for the price. According to [the documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield):

> This is a read-only field. It gets its value by calling a method on the serializer class it is attached to.

If you wish to pass an integer to your backend, you will have to use an `IntegerField`. In order to achieve your specialized functionality for retrieving the data, you can [specify the source attribute](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#source):

```
price = serializers.IntegerField(source='get_price')
```

This `get_price()` method may have to be moved to the model in order for this to work right.

Comment: Hello @Joey, yeah I've changed the field to be IntegerField, and moved get_price to the model, but now I'm getting TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'instancemethod', looks like is actually trying to return the method itself, not what it returns...any ideas?

Comment: Managed to fix that, but I can see in the validate method that what is passed as price is always a field called get_price, which eventually leads to errors again (check last value)...OrderedDict([(u'slug', u'object-object'), (u'description', u'yoyoy'), (u'name', u'Surf board'), (u'age', NumericRange(18, 65, u'[)')), (u'gender', 'F'), (u'num_sessions', 3), (u'school', <School: school_1>), (u'level', <Level: advanced>), (u'school_category', <Category: Surf <school_1>>), (u'get_price', 400)])